# How csurf middleware validates tokens?

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

I am testing `NodeJS express` app that uses `csurf` package along with `express-session` package.

**Problem**

While testing, i have to make requests that should include `csrf token` in them but because i don't really understand how `csurf` middleware validates `csrf tokens` in incoming requests, that is causing a lot of problems in testing the app.

**Question**

Can someone explain in simple terms, how `csurf` middleware validates `csrf tokens` when using `csurf` middleware with `express-session` package? How it validates token when it receives it in a request? Should tokens be sent in headers or in request body? Is new token created every time a new page is rendered or do we have once token per user session?

I also want to know how that the token validation process will change when using `csurf` middleware with `cookie-parser` package?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `csurf` works by storing a token secret into either the session (in the case of `express-session`) or directly into cookie (case of `cookie-parser`). The server side should then render the website with a dynamically generated (per request) token via `req.csrfToken()`. This csrf token is derived from token secret and can be verified later.

When calling `csurf` protected endpoints, this token should then  be included by client via body or header (see the default values [here](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf#value)). The middleware will then fetch the token secret from either the session or cookie, then verify it is a valid token generated by the secret owned by the user. If the verification fails, it will throw a csrf error.

Since csrf token generated is not time sensitive, for unit testing you can actually hardcode a same token secret into session or cookie, call `req.csrfToken()` once to receive a valid token, then keep on reusing the same token for every test.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not to issue a CSRF token per-request or per user session seems to be an area of debate, and even the top two answers on [this stackoverflow security question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/why-refresh-csrf-token-per-form-request) disagree on the matter.

### The Bottom Line:

We should always follow OWASP's recommendations which states that [per request CSRF tokens are more secure, but not necessary and can cause other problems](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#synchronizer-token-pattern).

> CSRF tokens should be generated on the server-side. They can be generated once per user session or for each request. Per-request tokens are more secure than per-session tokens as the time range for an attacker to exploit the stolen tokens is minimal. However, this may result in usability concerns.

**...**

It is worth noting though that the back button issue may not be a problem with csurf since it uses secret mechanism to generate/validate tokens (which allows old tokens to validate).

### Finally, if you are building an SPA:

The csurf documentation says to [only send down the CSRF token once on the route that renders the page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf#single-page-application-spa)